# Changing IP address of current server

Tags: ip-address, ifconfig

I have VM with IP address 10.10.10.99 how do I change the IP address to something else for e.g. 10.10.10.100 ? I have pinged to 10.10.10.100 and there is no such server in the network. Is there any other check necessary?

When I searched, I found that `ifconfig` and `ip addr` commands can be used for this. But I do not see how to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What OS and VM are you using? If you aren't adding a new IP and only updating the I'd just edit one of the two files depending if you are using a Debian flavored OS or a Redhat based OS

With Debian based (e.g., Ubuntu, Debian, Xandros, Mint) the change the settings in /etc/network/interfaces followed by:

```
service networking restart
```

RedHat based (e.g., Fedora, RHEL, CentOS) then you'd update /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 and then run

```
service network restart
```

Not sure if this is can even be updated outside of the OS. With xenserver I always just update in the OS.

As far as other things you would check it would depend on what subnet are on. I'm guessing since this is in RFC1918 space you are probably on 10.10.10.0/24 and so you'd be able to add it if no one else was using it.

Answer (score 0):

you should check in the VM program, on what status the Network card is, there are NAT in which is using DHCP, so it is more problematic to change the IP.

but nothing is preventing you to try what @Glen has suggested to you.